# DataFrame returns empty after .update()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I am trying to create a new DataFrame which contains a calculation from an original DF.
To that purpose, I run a for loop with the calc for each column, but I am still getting the empty original DF and I don't see where is the source of the error.
May I ask for some help here?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download(["YPFD.BA", "GGAL.BA"], period='6mo')
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ["YPFD.BA", "GGAL.BA"]:
    df2.update(df["Volume"][i] * df["Close"][i])

df2
```

I expected to create a new DF which contains the original index but with the calculation obtained from original DF

Comment: From my understanding of the `df.update()` function, is that it will replace **existing** values in one database with the values of another database. If no values exist in the dataframe, then there are no values to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking to do:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download(["YPFD.BA", "GGAL.BA"], period='6mo')
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ["YPFD.BA", "GGAL.BA"]:
    df2[i] = df["Volume"][i] * df["Close"][i]

df2
```

Comment: Indeed my friend, you are correct. Thank you very much!